# What bad things could happens if Geth RPC is public?

Tags: go-ethereum, security, json-rpc

Geth does not ship with RPC support. By default Geth enables modules `["net", "web3", "eth", "shh"]`. In case the RPC get compromised, what kind of bad things could happens?

Money lost will definitely be the first place

Assuming you have a wallet managed by Geth, people can freely sent any balance inside away.

Apart from money lost, is there any other things that may potential happens?

For example, if I just run the node as a block tracker and monitor if any money sent into my address. Does RPC has the ability to affect them as well?

Comment: Some functionality like complex filters can use lots of resources, if they are abused you can suffer a denial of service attack.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing bad is going to happen if you won't unlock any accounts on this node.
The blockchain data is public information so running RPC with * in rpccorsdomain is not an issue. 
RPC does not have any private info , it is the `personal` module that contains it.
do not call personal.unlockAccount() on your node and everything is going to be fine.

Neither store accounts info.

Answer (score 1):

Many bad things may happen, here is incomplete list of them:

1. Anybody may sign transactions/messages with your private keys as long as you unlock them
2. Anybody may use resources of your node to query blockchain state (some queries could be very CPU and HDD intensive)
3. Anybody may use resources of your node to publish large amounts of transactions, i.e. when performing DDOS attacks on Ethereum network
4. Anybody may exploit known RPC vulnerabilities in your node's software, especially in case your node's software is not up to date
5. Anybody may make your node unresponsive or even crash it by spamming with expensive queries

Comment: How could they spam with expensive (I assume high gas txs) queries?